# IndexError: string index out of range (can i have use 3 indexes at once?)

Tags: python, indexing, range, out

I'm having issues with the following error, and I have no idea why.

```
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Previously I was using it in a `for` loop and just assumed I was being an idiot, but I'm starting to think Python simply can't handle what I'm asking of it.

This is the specific line that the error is indicating:

```
print(location[5][1][0])
```

Here are the lists that it refers to:

```
location = ec
ec = (5,3, "Trader Outpost", plain_mobs, store, trader_outpost)
trader_outpost  = [filler,sword,shield,amulet]
sword = ["Sword ", 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 20, "Sword"]
```

What I though should happen is that Python...

1. Takes `location[5]` which is the list `trader_outpost`,
2. Then takes index 1 from `trader_outpost`, which is the list `sword`
3. Then takes index 0 from `sword`, which is the string `"sword"`

Is it simply impossible to go through lists like that?

EDIT: My main problem has been found: one of my variables wasn't passed through a function properly

SOLVED: I found the part of my code that was wrong. I had `location[2]` as one of the arguments for a function. This passed `"Trader Outpost"` to the one I had a problem in rather than the list.

Comment: Try printing out `location`, then `location[5]`, then `location[5][1]`, then `location[5][1][0]`, and see what each one is.  One of them is probably not what you think it is.

Comment: You look like you really need a *python* dictionary.

Comment: @Dunno That comment could read rather rude without context :)

Comment: @LevLevitsky heh, True, I edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are your instructions in the correct **order**? This works fine for me:

```
filler, sword, shield, amulet = 'f', 's', 'h', 'a'
plain_mobs, store = 'pm', 'st'

sword   = ["Sword "  ,0  ,0  ,0  ,5  ,0 ,20     ,"Sword"]
trader_outpost  = [filler,sword,shield,amulet]
ec = (5,3,  "Trader Outpost"        ,plain_mobs      ,store         ,trader_outpost)
location = ec

print(location[5][1][0])
=> Sword
```

So yes, you can have 3 indexes at once if every element encountered can be accessed by an index.

Comment: Im thinking that the value of "location" changes somewhere else in my code. trying to find that now.
but yes, it works fine for me when i do it like that too

Comment: @user3002588 I'm puzzled why you had the instructions in reverse order in your snippet... so the order is correct in your program?

Comment: I gave the instructions like that because my initial question was whether the issue was having 3 indexes all together like that. that question has been answered. Now I have another issue, except i dont know what that is